# Insert or replace Copyright Policy in every page on VS-2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have more then 1000 pages in my project.In every page of my project I have `Copyright Policy`.Now terms of  policy is change so I must have to open each and every page to `paste` my policy.Its so boring process and chance to missing some file.Find and replace all in entire solution not help much in this situation.So  Is there any built in method in `VS2010` to solve my problem ? Or is there any other alternative solution.Thanks.

Old One:

```
    #region "Copyright"
    /*
    Old Copyright 
.........................
    */
    #endregion
```

replace with New one:

```
    #region "Copyright"
    /*
    New Copyright 
....................
    */
#endregion
```

Comment: Do not repeat yourself: Add a file COPYRIGHT.TXT to your project and replace all those comments with `/* License: See COPYRIGHT.TXT */`.

Comment: use a macro or a micro-console app to do this for 1000 files !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could, you don't need to write a macro or other text-processing script to do this. Just use the "Find and Replace" feature built into Visual Studio.

You have a specific "old" format that you're replacing, down to the `#region "Copyright"` and `#endregion` lines that enclose the block, so this should be rather simple. "Find and Replace" even supports regular expressions.

Only problem is that Visual Studio (at least up to VS 2010, not sure if this changed in 2012) uses its own regex syntax. [Jeff Atwood has blogged about this before](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html), and you can find more info [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

However…I must say that I agree with [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541847/insert-or-replace-copyright-policy-in-every-page-on-vs-2010#comment25513099_17541847): it's ugly, annoying, and ultimately quite pointless to repeat legalese in *every code file*. All you have to do is include it in *one* file (named e.g. `COPYRIGHT` or `LICENSE`) and refer to it in the other files. Makes updating far easier, and prevents noise from cluttering up the code files. More thoughts on this can be found [here](http://hackerboss.com/get-rid-of-templates/), very much worth a read: it's both entertaining and true. Don't be a monkey.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take long to write another quick program in C# to read in your source files and replace the comment.  Or if you're lucky enough to use Resharper, it has a code cleanup feature that can add or update headers in source files.